# How to get matching server alias (Apache 2.4 / PHP)

Tags: php, apache

I have a service that I am developing actively. One very important part of logic is user id recognition from used domain. Web user arrives to address http://test.address.com (witch is alias for 1234567.address.com). Apache will serve content from document root (matching with ServerAlias).

Apache configs:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.address.com
    ServerAlias *.address.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Can I somehow detect and send matching server alias to PHP (with SetEnv or other ways)? PHP need to know address 1234567.address.com somehow. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes just get it from the HTTP_HOST environment variable. No need to send, it's already passed on by Apache. Use this:

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]
```

Ref: [PHP Predefined Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: Unfortunately it shows original address test.address.com. I need to know address behind it (1234567.address.com).

Comment: What do you mean, address behind it? If you visit 1234567.address.com, it will show that. If you visit test.address.com it will show that instead. Please explain what you mean about one being an alias for the other.

Comment: I spoke about DNS CNAME. Address test.address.com is CNAME for 1234567.address.com. I am not familiar with DNS and the way how browser handle these.

Comment: That information is not available directly, DNS setup is not know to Apache. You will have to work it out in the script based on what the DNS CNAME setup is, and what the HTTP_HOST is. It can't be accessed directly. And that's easy for you to do anyway. HTTP_HOST gives you what you need to work out the rest. Query DNS in PHP if you do want to access it directly, there is no reason to do anything at the Apache level.